# Installing pkg-config on OSX 10.6

Tags: linux, macos, pkg-config

Pardon a question from a non-linux guy.

I'm trying to build some source code that requires pkg-config on OSX 10.6.  I've found lots of instructions on how to do it, but they all require compiling pkg-config, and I get a variety of errors with each set of instructions.

If I knew more linux commands I'm sure it would be simple, but the time deadlines are such that I'd rather not become an expert in the creation and installation of a Linux tool.  If one of the gurus of linux can guide me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is off-topic for SO; possibly belongs on [apple.se] or [su]

Answer (score 2):

You can always use homebrew([Link](https://brew.sh/)) to install pkg-config and many other "linux" softwares on osx.

```sh
brew install pkg-config
```

Comment: Homebrew installed easily, and it seems to have installed pkg-config, but I still get the same error message. Homebrew complained because I have XCode 3.2.5, and I got the following message when I installed pkg-config:


"m4 macros were installed to "share/aclocal".
Homebrew does not append "/usr/local/share/aclocal"
to "/usr/share/aclocal/dirlist". If an autoconf script you use
requires these m4 macros, you'll need to add this path manually."  I'm not aware of using any m4 macros.

Comment: I tried doing a search for pkg-config and don't find it.  I have no idea if that makes a difference or not.  The results of the script seem to say it should be at /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.25, but there is no Cellar directory under /usr/local.

Comment: /usr/local/Cellar is the default install location of brew. I checked my brew installation, there is pkg-config under /usr/local/Cellar. You should check your brew installation.